# Connecting Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to run a JS file and testing in my terminal if I get an error or if I corrrecly added a new element to my database.
I have ran Mongodb, opened the terminal with "mongo" and finally run my app, cats.js.
When I run cats.js my terminal looks like this:

roots@goorm:/workspace/WDB/Databases# node cats.js

roots@goorm:/workspace/WDB/Databases#

..Basically nothing happens. What may I be missing? Thank you in advance.

I have the following JS:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);

var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    temperament: String
});

var Cat = mongoose.model("Cat", catSchema);


// adding a new cat to the database

var george = new Cat({
    name: "George",
    age: 11,
    temperament: "Grouchy",
});

george.save(function(err,cat){
    if(err){
        console.log("SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
    } else {
        console.log("WE JUST SAVED A CAT TO THE DATABASE");
        console.log(cat);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to your database.  Example:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

[Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I now have the following code upfront:
```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/cat_app", { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology", true);
```
When I run the node cats.js, it does print correctly that I added a new element to the database.

BUT I still get the following error: "DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated...pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true }" despite having paste: mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology", true);